# How to fix WebSocket connection to 'ws:localhost:8125/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: adobe-brackets

Coding in Brackets and working with JavaScript. When I go to Live Preview (and also using Enable Experimental Live Preview) to run code, this error message keeps coming up in Developer Tools (Chrome). How can I fix this?

I've tried other solutions from Stackoverflow but I'm uncertain as to how to resolve the problem. I'm kinda new to this, need someone to hold my hand through this or piece it together step by step.

Code is meaningless as it shows up in Live Preview accordingly. It's the error message under the the display that keeps coming up:

[image]

Comment: try these Troubleshooting steps [Troubleshooting Live Preview](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Troubleshooting#livedev)